# Set DHCP with manual IP

Tags: macos, networking, terminal, dhcp

Any idea how can we set a DHCP with manual IP address from the terminal OSX
(for a wifi interface)?

I know that this set a manual IP but not sure how to keep the DHCP:

`sudo ipconfig set en1 INFORM 192.168.0.150`

Comment: I don't understand what this question is asking for. DHCP isn't configured client-side (that's the point of DHCP), and DHCP is a protocol, not something you can "keep". Perhaps an [edit] to clarify what your end goal is might help. Please see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/157730) for more on this question pattern and why it is a poor way to ask questions.

Comment: Are you trying to set a reserved IP address so that a particular device always gets given the same IP from a DHCP server?

Comment: That the option I want to set http://s12.postimg.org/4gzyuh8sd/Screen_Shot_2015_06_15_at_14_21_30.png

Comment: You should read what the Apple support community says of *dhcp with manual address*, so you will change idea: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1663424

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your wi-fi service is named "Wi-Fi":

```
sudo networksetup -setmanualwithdhcprouter "Wi-Fi" 192.168.0.150
```

If the wireless service name is something else, you may need to use `networksetup -listallnetworkservices` or `-listnetworkserviceorder` to find its name